# Good design for reading a DIP Switch once

Tags: microcontroller, switches

I want to read an 8bit DIP switch at MCU startup, after that it will be disregarded. I have enough pins on the MCU to read this directly. My question is; is it worth while to stop the power for the switch after it is read? Power is not a huge consideration but as it will be on 24x7, running on large batteries I at least don't want wasteful usage. What would be the best practice? I could sacrifice one more pin on the MCU to do this.

Originally I was thinking of a multiplexor, but the price difference for an MCU with more pins is so small it would be easier to go that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything here assumes the switches are connected between microcontroller pins and ground, so that a closed switch reads zero.

Option 1:

Drive all your pullup resistors from a microprocessor pin.  This'll take an extra pin, but when you're done with it you can pull it low.

Option 2:

If you have a modern microcontroller, it has every kind of pull-up, pull-down, etc.  Usually the pins will be inputs on start-up (check the data sheet).  Assuming the processor allows it, set the pins to inputs with pull-ups.  Then wait a bit, then read your switches, then set the pins to pull-downs or as outputs and set them to 0.

Comment: Hi Tim, many thanks, another great solution, I will test it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use 1MOhm pull-up or pull-down resistors for low power.

You only need one pin and on transistor to disconnect all pull resistors from the power supply. You may not even need a pin.

I think you may be able to replace the transistor with a cap that automatically charges up to eventually prevent current flow. Just sample fast enough after power up before the cap voltage gets high enough to distort things.

Using a shared cap will cause the time window time to be different depending on switch states so if you don't want to use a big cap to accommodate for worst case (all closed switches), you may want separate caps for each switch.

Still, eight parallel 1MOhm resistors and a shared 1uF cap should give you 50ms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg1C23.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great solution, I will consider this for my implementation. Many thanks!

Comment: This will be very sensitive to EMI and moisture etc though.

Answer (score 3):

Many microcontrollers have internal pullups (and sometimes pulldowns).

Say you have the switch connected to short the inputs to ground and are using the internal pullups.

After the switch is read you can change the GPIOs to outputs (which will typically turn the pullups off) and set the latch to low and either set them to push-pull outputs or open-drain outputs (in that order, to avoid the possibility of a momentary short on the outputs which could cause the uC to glitch).

It's probably prudent to make sure a delay of some kind takes place before the inputs are read to allow the voltages to settle- just a hundred microseconds is more than enough. That may be taken care of elsewhere, for example if the chip reset is through a supervisory chip or internal circuit. Or maybe read it after clearing the memory.

Comment: Thanks, many great answers here, will do some testing and see which fits best with my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For high reliability systems, you often want so have something like a "configuration mode". Either a dedicated button or one of the dip switch inputs. When this mode is set, and only then, read the dip-switch. Otherwise use stored settings.

If the result read is different from what your MCU has stored in NVM, then write the read result to NVM. Otherwise do nothing.

This requires a MCU with useful NVM such as eeprom/data flash.

Optionally, read the switches multiple times.

The advantages of this method is that you don't have to worry about reading the dip-switch most of the time. If it should break over time because of poor soldering, oxidation etc, your program won't derail but use the previous settings.

In terms of current consumption, you only need to activate internal pull resistors when you are actually reading the dip-switch in configuration mode. Otherwise you can leave these floating.